# Best way to Figure out the next weekly schedule by specific day name

Tags: c#, datetime, schedule

imagine that i have a property called `NextSend` representing `DateTime` Value

`4/11/2011 10:30:00 AM - Monday`

lets say that I have a schedule which must be sent every week for specific day **`(Monday)`** in this case, so in order to figure out the next weekly schedule I ended up with the solution where I have to check every next date's day till the `DayOfWeek` Matches the `specific day` in the schedule

`4/`**17**/`2011 10:30:00 AM - Monday`

Is there any other best way to overcome checking each next day date's day name?

here is my mentioned logic:

```
  int nowYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
  int nowMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
  int nowDay = DateTime.Now.Day;
  int scheduleHour = this.Schedule.Time.Value.Hour;
  int scheduleMinute = this.Schedule.Time.Value.Minute;
  int scheduleSecond = this.Schedule.Time.Value.Second;
  int scheduleDay = -1;
  if(this.Schedule.Day.HasValue)
      scheduleDay= this.Schedule.Day.Value;

 switch (type)
            {
                case Schedule.ScheduleType.Weekly:
                    bool founded = false;
                    while (!founded)
                    {
                        //Check if last day of the current month
                        if (DateTime.DaysInMonth(nowYear, nowMonth) == nowDay)
                        {
                            //last day at this year, then move to next year
                            if (nowMonth == 12)
                            {
                                nowYear++;
                                nowMonth = 1;
                                nowDay = 1;
                            }
                            //its the end of a month then Move to next month
                            else
                            {
                                nowMonth++;
                                nowDay = 1;
                            }
                        }
                        //Get new proposed date
                        newNextSend = new DateTime(nowYear, nowMonth, nowDay, scheduleHour, scheduleMinute, scheduleSecond);

                        //Check if Next week schedule founded with specific day name
                        if (newNextSend.DayOfWeek ==
                            (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), Schedule.daysCalendar[scheduleDay - 1]))
                        {
                            founded = true;
                        }
                        else
                            nowDay++;
                    }
                    break;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As all the other folks have said as well: AddDays(7) will ensure the weekly schedule runs as required. But if you're looking for a way to figure out the next occurrence of a specific **weekday**, then you can do something like this:

```
private static DateTime GetNextDayOccurrence(DayOfWeek day, DateTime startDate)
{
    if (startDate.DayOfWeek == day)
    {
        return startDate;
    }
    else
    {
        return GetNextDayOccurrence(day, startDate.AddDays(1));
    }
}
```

Then a call like this

```
var nextWednesday = GetNextDayOccurrence(DayOfWeek.Wednesday, DateTime.Today);
```

will return the first occurrence of Wednesday. After which the weekly schedule carries on running. If you need the first occurrence of "Wednesday" as of next week, just pass

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(7)
```

to the "startDate" parameter of the above method.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, since the `Date` i'll start from might not be the same as last `nextSend`, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add 7 days to the original date? Number of days in a week is constant ;)

Next monday:

```
var nextMonday = thisMonday.AddDays(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use AddDays(7)?

e.g.

```
DateTime nextSheduleDate = scheduleDateTime.AddDays(7);
```

Here is a non-recursive version of Tobias' answer. Using the logic Daniel mentioned.

```
public static DateTime GetNextDayOccurrence(DateTime startDate, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
  var offset = startDate.DayOfWeek > dayOfWeek ? 7 : 0;
  var days = (int) dayOfWeek + offset - (int) startDate.DayOfWeek;

  var dateTime = startDate.AddDays(days);
  return dateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a method call `AddDays` which automatically handles month and year wraps.
2. Weeks are always 7 days long. Just add the difference between the current day of week and the day of week of the schedule.