# How to add Reminder in wp8 in specific day weekly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using `Reminder` class to add reminders, but don't how to make it to work on specific day (ever Monday once a week before 10:00 AM)

```
string name = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
Reminder reminder = new Reminder(name);
reminder.Title = "MyApp";
reminder.Content = "MyApp Message";
reminder.BeginTime = DateTime.Now;
reminder.ExpirationTime = DateTime.MaxValue;
reminder.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.Weekly;
//reminder.NavigationUri = navigationUri;

ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
```

How to make this reminder work every Monday once a week.

Thanks!

Comment: Just set the `BeginTime` property to the first Monday starting from the current day. It shouldn't be that difficult to code a function for this purpose. Do you need help with it?

Comment: Thanks, Good Idea! This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620141/best-way-to-figure-out-the-next-weekly-schedule-by-specific-day-name?rq=1) provided me a clear way